# Network plugin doesn't work on PWA app Ionic 4

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova-plugins, ionic4, progressive-web-apps

I use [network plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network) and it is working fine on the device on native/Cordova. But it is not working on the PWA app (i.e. when there is no `wifi`). Any reason for that? According to the above doc, it should work on the `browser` too.

**Note:** I have followed [this doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/publishing/progressive-web-app) to create a PWA app.

*network-state.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network/ngx';
import { ShowToastService } from './show-toast.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NetworkStateService {

  private connectSubscription$: Subscription = null;

  constructor(private network: Network,
    private showToastService: ShowToastService) { }

  WatchConnection() {
    if (this.connectSubscription$) { this.connectSubscription$.unsubscribe(); }
    this.connectSubscription$ = this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
      this.showToastService.showNetworkStateErrorToast('Your internet seems to be down! Please check your network settings!');
      if (this.connectSubscription$) { this.connectSubscription$.unsubscribe(); }
      this.connectSubscription$ = this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.showToastService.toast.dismiss();
          if (this.network.type === 'wifi' || this.network.type === '4g' || this.network.type === '3g' || this.network.type === '2g' || this.network.type === 'cellular' || this.network.type === 'none') {
            this.showToastService.showNetworkStateSuccessToast('Internet connection available!');
            this.WatchConnection();
          }
        }, 3000);
      });
    });
  }

}
```

*app.component.ts*

```
 async initializeApp() {
    await this.platform.ready();
    this.statusBar.styleDefault();
    this.splashScreen.hide();

    this.networkStateService.WatchConnection();// here

  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ionic Native it self only calls plugins when there is cordova available. In the [code here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/blob/master/src/%40ionic-native/core/decorators/common.ts#L188-L192), we check to see if cordova is on window and if not, we log a warning.

In the guide you're following, you're just publishing as a PWA using the standard angular browser build, which will not include cordova, nor should it. Since there is no cordova being included in the build, ionic-native is behaving as expected.

An alternative option here is to use capacitor, which has a [network plugin](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/network) and works better with existing deployment tools (angular, pwa)

Here's a link to a [getting started guide](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/getting-started/with-ionic) and a [reference guide](https://developer.school/posts/ionic-4-network-detection-with-capacitor/)

Comment: Oh.. This is exactly what I need to know about it. i.e. super man Capacitor. Thanks a lot.